# Why doesn't it keep incrementing every time I run the block?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm an absolute beginner, and I don't understand why a is not incremented every time I run the code. It always prints a = 0 and a = 1.

```
a = 0
b = 2

print ("a = {}".format(a))

a = a + 1

print ("a = {}".format(a))
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOhyY.png)

I'm working on Google Colab. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I just noticed if I keep the two first lines on a separate block [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59Brg.png), the code does increment. Why??

Comment: Because the very first line of code sets `a` to zero.

Comment: because each run involves re-compilation of py code. I don't think there is any shared state that is carried over between consecutive script runs; though you could use something like a cached file on a local drive for this purpose.

Comment: Right.  If you want numbers to carry over from run to run, then you need to store it in a file.  It is unfortunate that the convenient Python environments like Jupyter and Collab give beginning programmers the impression that variables last forever.

Comment: Re: your EDIT: why are you surprised?  If you don't reset `a`, then it still has its old value.

Comment: Ok, so if I keep the variables in the same block they reset, but if they're separate, their values are stored? I think I got it, thanks!

Comment: Oh, I gotcha; so you're using an environment similar to Jupyter notebook in that case. So yeah, the shared state that you were noticing definitely makes sense to me now. I forgot that it's possible to have stuff in different blocks and persist some data in that manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two separate cells, one for declaring the variables and one for incrementing:

[image: colab-example]